# Pass wire picklist value to connectedCallback

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a LWC where I am populating the picklist using wire service.

```
@wire(getPicklistValues , {recordTypeId: '$accountItem.data.defaultRecordTypeId',fieldApiName: ACCT_ITEM_STATUS })
acctStatus;
```

Wire populates picklist

```
  <template if:true={acctStatus.data}>
        <lightning-layout-item size="3" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-combobox value={value} placeholder="Complete" onchange = {handleAcctChange} options={acctStatus.data.values} label="Account Item Status" ></lightning-combobox>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>
```

2 Questions
1.How can I pass the the placeholder value to a connectedcallback?
2.How do I pass the picklist onchange value to the connectedcallback?

```
import getAcctLayout from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountItems';

async connectedCallback() {

const acctLayout = await getAcctLayout({acctId: this.recordId, acctStatus: picklist value})
```

Comment: 1. i belive placeholder value `complete`  is static ? why again you need to get from component 2.  why you need to pass picklist value connectedcallback event? for getAcctLayout function? what are you doing in getAcctLayout function? is any Apex server call?

Comment: 1.  Yes, 'complete' is a value in the picklist list.  I was trying to set it as a default.  I am trying to pass the picklist value to determine which records that will be selected in the Apex class that will determine what records to render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use reactive wire mechanism using `$`, added sample code

```
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getAcctLayout from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountItems';


   selectedPLValue = '';
   async connectedCallback() {
      this.selectedPLValue  = 'Complete'; // call wire service first time loads after set the value complete
   }
   @wire(getAcctLayout({acctId: this.recordId, acctStatus: '$selectedPLValue'}))
   acctLayout;

   handleAcctChange(event) {
       this.selectedPLValue  = event.detail.value; // call wire service when value changes
   }
```

Comment: So move getAcctLayout out of the connectedcallback?  Just want to confirm.  Also, will the updating the picklist value case the onchange to fire the connectedcallback? Thanks

Comment: yes make `getAcctLayout `  as wire service out from connectedcallback and call dynamically with reactive.  onchange event of picklist don't fire the connectedcallback ,it fires getAcctLayout  wire service after update the selected value

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.  For others info.  I moved the getAcctLayout code outside the connectedCallBack and used async instead or @wire.  I also made my changeEvent into async function.

Comment: still i don't understand the reason for using async & await. is there any specific scenario to use ?